# osmdroid - Import KML file of Areas

Tags: android, kml, osmdroid

I wanna show **areas** on the map, each area has its own .kml file, how can I import them to osmdroid and show them automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have **one** kml file for all **areas** not one file per area.

But you can [OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) to load kml file in osmdroid map.

Also you can see [this example](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3).

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer from Seyyed, and assuming these files are not too big:

You can have one kml file for each area, and then build a simple "global" file, referencing all these area files with a "NetworkLink" (look at to KML Reference if needed for the syntax).